# How to add scrollable tooltip HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a scrollable tooltip, are there existing scripts or ways to accomplish this with jquery or css? If so, how? I would like to avoid using iframe if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the tooltip is custom (i.e. triggered by a hover/click event), the HTML element used for the tooltip should be a fixed size with the CSS property, overflow:auto.

Answer (score 0):

The most accepted way is usually a DIV with it's position:absolute and display:none.  Once the mouse is over the tooltip area some javascript can show the DIV at the correct position (beside the mouse).

This method will allow any size DIV including a those with a scroll.